# Android listview, change attributes of particular view

Tags: java, android, listview, view

on my listview I am scrolling to a particular position of it like this

getListView().smoothScrollToPosition(scrollposition+1);

but I also want to "highlight" this view. How do I access the attributes of this particular view to change the background color of this position.

Here is the listview code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/currentText"
    android:padding="10dp" android:textSize="24sp" android:textColor="#000000" android:background="@drawable/bglistitem"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
</TextView>
```

It is just a textview with a background. I tried doing this:

```
View highlightView = getListView().getChildAt(scrollposition);
highlightView.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#2580b0"));
TextView currentText = (TextView)highlightView.findViewById(R.id.currentText);
currentText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

but it always crashes! I can understand why `setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor`crashes, but even getting the textview from that view crashes.

Help?

Comment: how does it crash ? What logs ?

Comment: nullpointerexception on setDrawingCache. If I comment out setDrawingCash then it nullpointerexceptions on the textview assignment. So the View itself isn't being filled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a few weeks ago.

You should not use the getChildAt() function of the ListView. If you use getChildAt(5), for example, it will pull the 5th view that is *visible*.

To solve the issue, I had to create a custom adapter that overrode getView() and set the colors based on what I sent across.

```
  public class RunAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public RunAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items,
        int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, items, resource, from, to);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView txtView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lstTurnout);
        if (txtView.getText().toString().contains("BLU")) {
            txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0x00, 0x00, 0xaa));
            txtView.setText(txtView.getText().toString().replace("BLU", ""));
        } else {
            txtView.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(0xaa, 0x00, 0x00));
            txtView.setText(txtView.getText().toString().replace("RED", ""));
        }
  }
```

It isn't the prettiest method, but it works!
Depending on what color I wanted the TextView to be, I passed 'BLU', or 'RED'
Then in the getView, I check to see which the string contains and change the color accordingly.

Hope I was some help, Good Luck!

*Edit*
Constructor as per request

Comment: Ah, yes I've done custom adapters, I was thinking I wouldn't have to do that for this issue. Can I see your constructor?

Comment: ListViews are seriously strange... it took me a while to get my head wrapped around them, this method is a bit unorthodox, but I have had no issues with it.

Comment: It uses a list of HashMap<String,String> with each HashMap value containing <key, value> if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

getChildAt needs an index, not a scrollpostion.

Regards,
 Stphane

Comment: scrollposition is an integer that tells the it what view to go to. it contains the index I want