# Android List view change colour depending on content

Tags: android, listview

I've currently got a `ListView` `Adaptor`.

How do i change the color of the background of `ListView` depending on the of the `ListView` item?

```
i.e if(item.param1 == "some")
{
colour1
}
else
{
colour2
}
```

---

My code

```
   import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.List;

   import android.content.Context;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.view.ViewGroup;
   import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
   import android.widget.TextView;

   public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFF000000 };
    TextView tv1, tv2;

    public SpecialAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> items, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, items, resource, from, to);
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

      view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
      return view;
    }
    }
```

Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: Are you wanting to change the background of the `ListView` or the background of the particular `View` the item is associated with?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086133/android-listview-change-attributes-of-particular-view/7086301#7086301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should override

```
getViewTypeCount()
```

and

```
getItemViewType(int position)
```

inside your ListAdapter to define different types for each Color. The Solution to change the Color in BindView only will not give a good result because the Listview recycles the ListItems so you end up changing the color of the recyled items back and forth.

When providing a ViewTypeCount > 1 the Listview knows you use different Layouts and provide you with a appropriate recyled ListItem.
see this Tutorial for more information.

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296